# Change the default value in a built-in function

Tags: r, default-value

I was wondering if it is possible to change the default value for a built-in function in R? I have found some questions about setting default values for user made functions in R, but not for built-in functions.

Why do I want this? To be honest, it is purely a matter of convenience. Sometimes I write my results/data to a .csv file to make some quick graphs in Excel. To do this I use the `write.csv` function. One of the defaults in this function is `row.names = TRUE`. So far, I have never wanted the row.names in my Excel file and I have forgotten to add `row.names = FALSE`  to the function dozens of times. So is it possible to change the default value in this function to `row.names = FALSE`?

Comment: For your particular use case, you might try `write_csv` from the readr package.  Description: *This is about twice as fast as write.csv, and never writes row names.*  Using a new function, either your own wrapper or from a package, will also make your workflow more reproducible than setting software-specific defaults.

Comment: there is an archived [Defaults](http://cran.wustl.edu/web/packages/Defaults/index.html) package, but @ZheyuanLi's answer will be much easier than trying to install an out-of-date package

Comment: If you do not make the extra step of documenting the changing of default, you are making your script less reproducible. Think 1 month or 1 year down the line. FWIW, I never forget to add/change any parameters (if I happen to do so, I get a warning/error), so it's possible to work around the defaults. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. But if you want convenience, write a wrapper function yourself. For example:

```
my_write.csv <- function(...) write.csv(..., row.names = FALSE)
```

then you use `my_write.csv`.